# Apache POI XLSX export with Rest API

Tags: java, rest, apache-poi, xlsx, xmlbeans

i'm trying to make an export system using Java and Rest API but i got this error :  ***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException*** 
I'm using the same code here : http://www.quicklyjava.com/write-to-xlsx-file-in-java-using-apache-poi/
and i added this :

```js
@GET
 @Path("/excel")
 @Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Comment: So did you look for xmlbeans in maven?  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.6.0

Comment: i found the error but now how can i download file in ajax response ?

Comment: You’ll need to post example code for help with that one. Or a new question.